# Parsing JSON data from WebService on a background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, background

I have a method that builds a package, sends it to a web service, gets a package back, opens it and returns me a nsdictionary. How can I call it on a background queue in order to display a HUD while it requests the data?

Comment: Have you looked into ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetworking? They make this process very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could detach a new thread like following

```
- (void) fetchData
{
     //Show Hud

    //Start thread
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getDataThreaded) 
    toTarget:self  
    withObject:nil];
}

- (void) getDataThreaded
{    
   //Start Fetching data

   //Hide hud from main UI thread
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI if you have to
        //Hide Hud
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grand central dispatch (gcd) provides great support for doing what you ask.  Running something in the background using gcd is simple:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0) ^{
   NSDictionary* data = [self fetchAndParseData];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self dataRetrieved:data];
   });
});
```

This call will return immediately (so your UI will continue to be responsive) and `dataRetrieved` will be called when the data is ready.

Now, depending on how fetchAndParse data works it may need to be more complicated.  If you NSURLConnection or something similar, you might need to create an NSRunLoop to process data callbacks on the gcd thread.  NSURLConnection for the most part is asynchronous anyway (though callbacks like didReceiveData will be routed through the UI thread) so you can use gcd only to  do the parsing of the data when all the data has been retrieved.  It depends on how asynchronous you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous replies, why don't you use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` classes? These classes are abstractions under GCD and they are very simple to use.

I like `NSOperation` class since it allows to modularize code in apps I usually develop.

To set up a `NSOperation` you could just subclass it like

```
//.h
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation

@end

//.m
@implementation MyOperation()

// override the main method to perform the operation in a different thread...
- (void)main
{
    // long running operation here...
}
```

Now in the main thread you can provide that operation to a queue like the following:

```
MyOperation *op = [[MyOperation alloc] initWithDocument:[self document]];
[[self someQueue] addOperation:op];
```

P.S. You cannot start an async operation in the `main` method of a `NSOperation`. When the `main` finishes, delegates linked with that operations will not be called. To say the the truth you can but this involves to deal with run loop or concurrent behaviour.

Here some links on how to use them.

- http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/
- https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html

and obviously the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSOperation`